# Access response object from json promise with fetch() in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, scope, fetch

With the following code:

```
fetch(url, params).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(json => {
    // json handler
    if (!response.ok) { // <-- Does not work, I don't have access to response object here
        if (json.error)
            throw new Error(json.error); // Application spesific error
        else
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.statusText}(${response.status})`); // Generic error
    }
    console.log('Success:', json);
}).catch((e) => {
    console.error("Failed with:", e);
});
```

I have a problem where I can't get access to the `response` object from the `json` handler. I can't store response in a global variable because obviously that is a bad idea for many reasons. I can't use `this` as it simply points to `window`.

So what would be the proper way of passing the `response` object along to the `then()` handler of the `json()` promise in this case?

Comment: You can perform your `response.ok` check in your first `.then()` callback?

Comment: @NickParsons: I tried this first, but then I don't have access to the error from server which is only available in json handler :D

Comment: Testing `response.ok` after you've used the response doesn't make that much sense

Comment: `.then(res => Promise.all([res.json(), res])).then(([json, res]) => ...)`

Comment: Switch to `async`/`await` syntax. It makes scope much easier to deal with.

Comment: @LennartRolland You probably want to do one check in your first `.then()` and throw your http error if `!response.ok`, and then another check in your second `.then()` and throw your application error if `json.error` occurs